# ALS Algorithm Spark MLlib - How do I get my own " Personal Recomendations" (Rankings for the movies I haven't ranked)

Tags: python, machine-learning, pyspark, apache-spark-ml

I am using PySpark within Azure Databricks. I used Sparks MLlib Library ALS Algorithm to predict movie ratings which works successfully. However, I am trying to add a dataframe that consist of my ratings for 10 randomly selected movies. When I do this I only get prediction rankings for movies I have already ranked.

I want to be able to use the model to get recommendations based on their rankings.

I have Spark Code that performs the following tasks:

- Imports Data (RatingsSmall, MoviesSmall, RatingsLarge, Movies Large)
- Merge Ratings small with Movies Small, Merge Ratings Large with Movies Large
- Append to two new Datasets together
- Drop irrelevant columns Timestamp and Genre

I now have a clean table which has MovieID, Title (Movie Name),UserID and Ranking. I will show the code from this point. If you would like the code before this then I can submit this too.

- Split the Data into Training and Test Set (0.80, 0.20)
- ALS Algorithm
- Display predictions.

Hopefully the above helps you guide through the code I have attached.
I only get predictions for rankings I have already submitted.

I have tried to join my rankings to the training set.  From here I would like to get recommendations or predictions for the other movies in the dataset.

My attempt:
imported a DF with my own rankings.
Appended this (UnionAll) to the training set.
Got predictions (but only for movies I have already ranked)

code:

```
#Split dataset

    training, test = All_Movies.randomSplit([0.8, 0.2])
    from pyspark.ml.recommendation import ALS

    from pyspark.ml.evaluation import RegressionEvaluator

#Set up model

    ALS = ALS(maxIter=10, regParam=0.01, userCol = "userId",itemCol="movieId", ratingCol="rating",  coldStartStrategy="drop")

#Fit model to Training set and attach personal recomendations


     model = ALS.fit(training.unionAll(PersonalDF)) #PersonalDF is my rankings

#Get Predictions for Test Set
    predictions = model.transform(test).dropna()

#All good up until here.

#Trying to get prediction rankings for my movies
    mySampledMovies = model.transform(PersonalDF) 
    mySampledMovies.registerTempTable("mySampledMovies")

    display(sqlContext.sql("select userId, movieId, rating,title, prediction from mySampledMovies"))
```

I expect a DataFrame that says my userID, MovieID,Ranking, Prediction. For movies I haven't seen ranking to be N/A or Null and Predictions to have a value.

Many Thanks